# Error missing namespace or assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am writing the code right, but getting error - missing namespace or assembly reference.Is there something wrong with the code or I am missing something?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2 };

            do
            {
                {
                    sum += arr[1];
                    Console.WriteLine("Wow");
                    i++;
                }
            }
            while (i < 3);
        }
    }
}
```

> Error is : Error Cannot initialize type 'int' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable

Comment: what 'using' statements do you have?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
Add these and your problem should solve

Comment: using System; should be enough.

Comment: @mahditahsildari: `System.Collections.Generic`? `System.Linq`? Those are not necessary.

Comment: -1 Please include the **exact** error message.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth :) you're right i did it on hurry

Comment: ok i updated the complete code now but still getting an error - posted error too in bottom

Comment: @Geek - Posted code seems OK to me. Please check the syntax in your code editor of array initializer - `int []ar=new int() {1,2}` This code will throws such exception.

Comment: thanks avd i manage to solve the code with the help you guys thanks all :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> i am writing the code right

Don't start with this assumption. Always start with the assumption that the compiler is correct, and your code is wrong.

You haven't shown any `using` directives. In this case all you need is

```
using System;
```

(Either at the very top of your code or within the `namespace` declaration.)

or change your `WriteLine` call to:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Wow");
```

If that *doesn't* fix it (or if you've already got such a `using` directive but forgot to include it), then your project is probably somewhat broken - it's not like you're using any exotic types.

Comment: Supp Skeet, its like you live on Stackoverflow, Good Day man!

Comment: @Geek: Then the code you posted isn't the code you're compiling, and I don't see how we're meant to fix it...

Comment: @jon thanks i managed to solve the problem thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 59):

My namespace ended in `Console` (i.e. `MyProject.Console`) which messed up the calls to `Console.Write`. In this case, either write the fully qualified name `System.Console.Write` or change the namespace.

Comment: So easy to do, so difficult to realize the problem!

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Import the `System` namespace or just use `System.Console.WriteLine("...");`

```
using System;

namespace TestNs
{
   public class Test
    {
      static void Main() 
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. The namespace name I used ended with .Console, so there was a conflict with System.Console

```
using System;

namespace Test.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I changed Test.Console to Test.ConsoleApp, and problem fixed for me

```
using System;

namespace Test.ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

The minimum for your console app should have this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to ReSharper, my code would have only one of those directives .. (but only after using `Console`).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all for help i managed to solve the problem with the help of you guys :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i = 0; //initialize integer i=0
            int sum = 0; // initialize integer sum = 0;
            int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}; // array containing 4 integers elements
            do
            {

                {
                    sum+=arr[i];    //sum each integer in array and store it in var sum

                    i++;        //increment i for each element of array
                    Console.WriteLine(sum); //output the var sum conatining values after each increment
                }

            }
            while(i<=3); //check condition for number of elements in array

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a namespace of `Myproject.App` also causes problems, in the same way as `MyProject.Console` (as per contactmatt's answer, above).